# Are captchas need for my online form

Tags: captcha, online-forms

I have an online form in asp.net which using the jQuery wizard, and was not sure my last stage would need a captcha control to prevent bots/crawlers.

So would I need a captcha? for my online web form...?? Is it recommended??

Comment: Are you concerned that bots will be negatively affecting your site? To keep out crawlers is easy if you the content you want protected requiring authentication first.

Answer (score 1):

Captcha is recommended if your application/form is being attacked by bots. If you feel, there are attacks and you have sensitive information, you can opt for captcha (or recaptcha).

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to make it public, i.e. providing form to invited users only, then, you probably don't need Captcha. But, if it is going to be open to public,(like gmail for example) then, its definitely recommended to put captcha in the form.